# vbscript - email generator to write data from InputBox to array and then crete X amount of emails

Tags: arrays, vba, email, vbscript, outlook

Journey continues.

In this episode I want to try to make a script responsible for generating emails.

Right now I have InputBox which puts all ; separated email addresses into one email but I would want it to make one email per address.
I was thinking to put all the emails from inputReqM into array and then read from it one line at a time.
Second thing - array should make it possible to change user's name, i.e. john.doe@nowhere.com to Dear John, in email head.
Can you help me out, please?

```
inputReqM = ReqMail.Value `email addresses divided using ;
inputCC = CCmail.Value    
InputReqN = ReqName.Value `user's name (typed in manually)

dim objOutl, objMailItem
Set objOutl = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set objMailItem = objOutl.CreateItem(olMailItem)

objMailItem.SentOnBehalfOfName = ""
objMailItem.Display
objMailItem.To = inputReqM
objMailItem.cc = inputCC
objMailItem.bcc = ""
objMailItem.Subject = inputTkt & ""
objMailItem.HTMLBody = "<body style="" font:11pt/14pt Calibri, Arial, serif"">" &     vbNewLine &_
"Dear " & inputReqN & ",<p>" & vbNewLine &_

Set objMailItem = nothing
Set objOutl = nothing
```

I would like InputreqN to be taken from array as well.
Thank you.

Comment: I came up with: 

`dim inputText 
dim mainArray 
Dim objOutl 
Set objOutl = CreateObject("Outlook.Application") 
Set objMailItem = objOutl.CreateItem(olMailItem) 
inputText = InputBox("put emails here separated with ;","","") 
mainArray = split(LCase(inputText),";") 
for each x in mainArray 
objMailItem.Display 
objMailItem.To x 
objMailItem.Subject = "" 
objMailItem.Body = "" 
next` 

but I get "the object does not support this method" for objMailItem.To x

Comment: OK. seems i was missing "=" :)
`objMailItem.To = x`

but that doesn't cut it quite.
still I get only one email populated with last email entered into inputbox.
any ideas?

Comment: could you also put into the answer how you are splitting the Array and the rest of your code, it is quite impossible to read code put into the comment-box

Answer (score 0):

```
dim inputText
dim mainArray
dim objOutl
dim objMailItem

Set objOutl = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set objMailItem = objOutl.CreateItem(olMailItem)

inputText = InputBox("put emails here separated with ;","","")
mainArray = split(LCase(inputText),";")

    for each x in mainArray
        objMailItem.Display
        objMailItem.To = x
        objMailItem.Subject = ""
        objMailItem.Body = ""
    next
```

Now if I'm gonna remove four `objMailItem's` under `for each` and replace them with `output=output & x & vbCRLF` and add `msgbox output` under `next`, I get all entries listed like: 
mail@mail.com
mail@mail2.com
mail@mail3.com
etc

Hope that helps you understand. That's all I have.
Thanks.